# IFormFile is null when Form in Razor Page submitted by JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, iformfile

When I submit Form in a Razor Page by click on Submit button, IFormFile send to OnPost action method properly. But if I submit the Form by JavaScript code, IFormFile is null in OnPost action method, other model members are not null.

Model

```
public string Applicant { get; set; }  
public List<IFormFile> FormFiles { get; set; }
```

Form

```
<form method="post" name="ApplicantForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input asp-for="@Model.ApplicantModel.Applicant" />
    <input type="file" asp-for="@Model.ApplicantModel.FormFiles" multiple />
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="doSomethingBeforeSubmit()">Do Something Before Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function doSomethingBeforeSubmit() {
    // Do something before submitting the form ...
    .
    .

    document.forms["ApplicantForm"].submit();
     // Or
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
}
```

OnPost action method

```
[BindProperty]
public ApplicantModel ApplicantModel { get; set; } 
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
     ApplicantModel.Applicant // OK, Always .. 
     ApplicantModel.FormFiles // OK, if form submitted by click on Submit button.
     ApplicantModel.FormFiles // Null, if form submitted by JavaScript code.    
}
```

What is the right way to submit a form by JavaScript code in Razor Page with IFormFile in model?

.NET 6,
Visual Studio 2022,
ASP.NET Core Web App (Razor Pages)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass files with js,you need to use `FormData`,here is a demo:

```
function doSomethingBeforeSubmit() {
        var Form_Data = new FormData();
        Form_Data.append('ApplicantModel.Applicant', $("#ApplicantModel_Applicant").val());
        var files = $("#ApplicantModel_FormFiles").get(0).files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            Form_Data.append('ApplicantModel.FormFiles', files[i]);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '',
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            data: Form_Data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                
            },
            error: function (result) {
                
            }
        })
    }
```